# i want to create .js file on fly using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

**This is my code:**

```
private void CreateJSFile(string jsString)
{
    //before minification I want to create a .js file and insert that bit of
    //code in that file and then minify that file
    var minifier = new Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Minifier();
    var minifiedString = minifier.MinifyJavaScript(jsString);
}
```

I want to create .js file and add that `jsString` into that file then minify that file. I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript file is a simple file with .js extension, You can create the file and then insert your code here is the link to create file in C#. [How to create file in C#?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx). To compress the file you can look into the below stackoverflow answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234213/how-to-compress-javascript-files-using-c